# Facebook Application Invitation Automatically

Tags: php, facebook

im developing a new facebook application and need to send Appusers frind list application invite.

Example, 
my friend X logged CityVille App,
my friend is offline but he send CityVille Invite. 
i ask to X you send this invite ? he said no :) Invite getting from city ville Automatically. (No fb dialog)

How can i do this.

P.S:
My App Required permissions is:
email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_photos,read_friendlists

I tried following code on my friendlist, but i dont send invitation returing error

```
$app_id = $this->facebook_config['appId'];
$app_secret = $this->facebook_config['secret'];

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
            "client_id=" . $app_id .
            "&client_secret=" . $app_secret .
            "&grant_type=client_credentials";

$app_access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

$user_id = 'USERID';

$apprequest_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
                $user_id .
                "/apprequests?message='Mesaj'" . 
                "&data='bisi'&"  .   
                $app_access_token . "&method=post";

$r = file_get_contents($apprequest_url);



echo $r;
```

`error
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "(#200) All users in param ids must have accepted TOS"
   }
}`

Comment: i want to send application invite without facebook invitation dialog box.

Comment: spammer, -1, why would u want to annoy users like that?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you're asking about requests to **use** or **invite** users to the application rather than **do something** in the application. Well AFAIK the only way to do this is by emailing them. Facebook just don't allow this anymore, other that the default Facebook invite dialog.

The Facebook's API `apprequests` is to send request between the connected users only e.g. get this lost cow, or help me to win this battle ... etc.

---

**Update**: The proper way invite friends to connect is by using Facebook JavaScript SDK.

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Plz add this, I need you to use this app desperately!',
    to: 'any-friend-id'
});
```

I've just tested it and it allowed my brother to [use it](https://apps.facebook.com/tipntag-app/).

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is most likely caused by your use of `file_get_contents`.

I would suggest using curl for this:

    `$ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apprequest_url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);`

Please be aware that (last time I checked) you must still prompt the user with some form of dialog before sending any app requests/invites. Doing it without a user's expressed permission is against FB's guidelines.

You can test the functionality of your request with the API explorer: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=me%2Fapprequests

Comment: I tried Curl but returned same error 

{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#200) All users in param ids must have accepted TOS"}}

Comment: Is the user ID you're passing a confirmed connected user to your application?